# windows cannot acess the specified device path or specified file (CD drive, sdxc card) Windows 10

Tags: usb, sd-card, windows-10-v1809, cd-drive

attempting to run any exe file results in the error "windows cannot acess the specified device path or specified file or you may not have appropriate permissions)

things i have tried to resolve the issue

plugging the devices into a different usb ports, adding Deny_Execute dword key in HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Storage and then setting it to 0 and checking gpedit permissions

this only effects my sdxc card (kingston canvas go plus 64gb) and my external lenovo branded cd drive all my other external drives work perfectly fine and are unaffected

i am using windows 10 ltsc 2019

both of these drives worked perfectly fine before i downgraded from windows 11 to 10 ltsc

NOTE: i want to make this more clear i cannot run exes from my sd card but i can run exes perfectly fine in windows on my c drive

Comment: Hard to say what might have happen trying to upgrade to Windows 11 and back again. Should be OK but remains a question. You do not need to change the registry to run decent cards or devices.  Try running DISM / SFC ( I do not think this will work but it costs nothing to try).  .....   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: i also tried that and it didn't help and i have just found out that this is happening with any usb flash drives i plug in

Comment: Trying to run ANY exe? Also, are these exes on the SD card having this issue, or only happening WHEN that SD card is inserted? Please EDIT your question to make things more clear.

Comment: Also relevant: LTSC is not intended as a general purpose OS model. It is appropriate for kiosks, embedded systems, or systems very like embedded systems. It is not designed for use in regular-use desktops and laptops, and its feature set is NOT comparable to "regular" Windows 10. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/ltsc-what-is-it-and-when-should-it-be-used/ba-p/293181

Comment: the issue is only happening on some of my external drives i can run any exe perfectly well in windows from my c drive but cant run them from the sd card

Comment: @music2myear and i know ltsc isnt for regular use but many people do use for that since it is less bloated than regular windows 10 also i have had other computers with ltsc installed and running exes from external drives was never an issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i have resolved the issue apparently i had a windows asr rule in windows defender which prevented me from running some exe files thank you everyone trying to help me

Answer (score 0):

I suggest now (given LTSC) and that DISM did not work (likely because of this) that you will need to back up completely and reinstall LTSC 2019.

Repair Install will not work either as it wants to update to current.